# Complex C++ data types and COM

Tags: c++, com, asp-classic

I wish to access a dll's functionality from ASP Classic and my understanding is that COM is the way to go.

The .h header file associated with the dll looks something like this:

```
...

struct _Data;

typedef struct _Field
{
    INT  iType;
    BOOL bChanged;
    INT  iFieldId;
    INT  iInternalFieldId;  
    INT  iLenght;
    INT  iDec;
    RW iRW;
    union
    {
        DOUBLE    d;
        CHAR*     s;
        LONG      l;
        BOOL      b;
        LONG      date;
        struct _Data* data;
    }
    value;
} FIELD;

typedef struct _MetaData
{
    HANDLE hHandle;
    INT        iDatabaseId;
    INT        iFields;
    INT        iStructSize;
} META;

typedef struct _Data
{
    META  metaData;
    FIELD rgField[MAX_FIELD];
} DATA, *PDATA;

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif //__cplusplus

    __declspec(dllexport) P_DATA __stdcall CreateData(INT iDatabaseId);
    __declspec(dllexport) ERROR __stdcall GetStr(DATA* pData, INT iFieldId, CHAR** ppsValue, INT iLen);

...
```

So as you can see the functions themselves as straightforward but the data is rather complex.

How should I go about defining such datatypes for my COM Server?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 2):

There is no structure type in the script languages like VBScript and JScript, used with ASP in most IIS applications. You can't declare a structure variable to receive the return value or pass it to a C++ function.

You need to wrap the structures into automation types. Write an automation server class that implement IDispatch, and expose structure members as properties of simple automation types, or other automation server classes (e.g. a collection class with Count and Item properties). See ["Passing Structures through IDispatch" by Don Box, Microsoft Systems Journal, June 1996.](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0696/activex0696.aspx)